# Thrift install error

Tags: java, ant, thrift

I get this error when i try to install thrift on Ubuntu 12.04.
I use ant 1.9.1 an install thrift 0.9.
when i try 'make' command i got this error.
Can anybody help me show this error. Thanks.

make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/opt/thrift-0.9.0'
Making all in compiler/cpp
make[2]: Entering directory`/opt/thrift-0.9.0/compiler/cpp'
make  all-am
make[3]: Entering directory `/opt/thrift-0.9.0/compiler/cpp'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for`all-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/opt/thrift-0.9.0/compiler/cpp'
make[2]: Leaving directory`/opt/thrift-0.9.0/compiler/cpp'
Making all in lib
make[2]: Entering directory `/opt/thrift-0.9.0/lib'
Making all in cpp
make[3]: Entering directory`/opt/thrift-0.9.0/lib/cpp'
Making all in .
make[4]: Entering directory `/opt/thrift-0.9.0/lib/cpp'
make[4]: Nothing to be done for`all-am'.
make[4]: Leaving directory `/opt/thrift-0.9.0/lib/cpp'
Making all in test
make[4]: Entering directory`/opt/thrift-0.9.0/lib/cpp/test'
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[4]: Leaving directory`/opt/thrift-0.9.0/lib/cpp/test'
make[3]: Leaving directory `/opt/thrift-0.9.0/lib/cpp'
Making all in java
make[3]: Entering directory`/opt/thrift-0.9.0/lib/java'
/opt/ant1.91/bin/ant 
Buildfile: /opt/thrift-0.9.0/lib/java/build.xml

setup.init:

mvn.ant.tasks.check:

proxy:

mvn.ant.tasks.download:
      [get] Getting: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-ant-tasks/2.1.3/maven-ant-tasks-2.1.3.jar
      [get] To: /opt/thrift-0.9.0/lib/java/build/tools/maven-ant-tasks-2.1.3.jar
      [get] Not modified - so not downloaded

mvn.init:

BUILD FAILED
/opt/thrift-0.9.0/lib/java/build.xml:282: artifact:pom doesn't support the "groupId" attribute

Total time: 1 second
make[3]: *** [all-local] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/opt/thrift-0.9.0/lib/java'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory`/opt/thrift-0.9.0/lib'
make[1]:**  [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/thrift-0.9.0'
make: ** [all] Error 2

Answer (score 2):

This error is caused by Apache Ant 1.9.x. Refer to [[1](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/thrift/?comments=all)] for more info.

1. Remove apache ant, and reinstall with version 1.8.x [[2](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/apache-ant.html)]

   > ```
   > # sudo apt-get remove ant
   > # tar -jxvf http://archive.apache.org/dist/ant/source/apache-ant-1.8.4-src.tar.bz2
   > # cd apache-ant-1.8.4/
   > # sed -i 's;jars,test-jar;jars;' build.xml
   > # sudo mkdir /opt/ant-1.8.4
   > # sudo ./build.sh -Ddist.dir=/opt/ant-1.8.4 dist
   > # sudo ln -v -sfn ant-1.8.4 /opt/ant
   > ```
2. Configure thrift [[3](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/th/thrift/PKGBUILD)]

   > ```
   > # export PATH=$PATH:/opt/ant/bin
   > # export ANT_HOME=/opt/ant
   > # PYTHON=/usr/bin/python2 ./configure --prefix=/usr --without-ruby
   > # make
   > # sudo make install
   > ```

Answer (score 2):

I am using thrift 0.9.1 on Ubuntu 12.04 and I found the same problem occurred regardless of ant 1.8.4 or 1.9.4:

**...artifact:pom doesn't support the "groupId" attribute**

What really helped was this suggestion: [http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/RunningCassandraInEclipse#artifact:pom_error](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/RunningCassandraInEclipse#artifact%3apom_error)

You have to ensure the maven-ant-tasks-2.1.3.jar file is in the lib directory for the active version of ant you are using.